# How to force SQLAlchemy to make a fresh select from the database instead of reusing object from memory/session?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm writing tests for the repository layer in my project and am using `SQLAlchemy 2.0.25` with `PostgreSQL 15.3`.

I have an `insert_or_update(name: str)` function that makes an `insert().on_conflict_do_update()` in the database, with `returning()` which will correctly insert/update the new row in the table and then return the resulting operation as an object.

While debugging I can see the memory address on that object.

In my test I then make changes to that object and call the `insert_or_update()` function again.

Lastly I try to make a `select()` on that same row expecting SQLAlchemy to return me **new** object so I can compare them and ensure the values were updated correctly and that only the values that can be updated were changed.

However, when debugging I see that both objects (the result from the `insert_or_update()` and the `select()`) have the same memory address and noticed that, obviously, when I change a value on one of them, the other is altered as well.

I read about how `SQLAlchemy` handles sessions and how it will identify that I'm trying to select a value that it has selected already, and to be more efficient, it will return me the value cached in the session instead. My question is, for my tests, I prefer that `SQLAlchemy` does a fresh `select()` from the database but I couldn't make that work yet.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Read [SQLAlchemy's official documentation on `Session cache`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sqlalchemy's on\_conflict\_do\_update.returning to return updated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566275/how-to-use-sqlalchemys-on-conflict-do-update-returning-to-return-updated-values)

Comment: I found my own answer when researching an answer to your question.  Hopefully you can see link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566275/how-to-use-sqlalchemys-on-conflict-do-update-returning-to-return-updated-values